# System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error occurs while trying to store textbox value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to store textbox's text into string variable but an error occurs:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Code:

```
 Dim Name As String = txtName.Text
Dim Email As String = txtEmail.Text
Dim Password As String = txtPassword.Text
Dim Repassword As String = txtRepassword.Text
Dim Country As String = txtCountry.Text
Dim College As String = txtCollege.Text
Dim Phone As String = txtPhone.Text
```

It shows that `txtName.text` is NULL; how can I fix it?

My control code is here:

```
'''<summary>
'''txtName control.
'''</summary>
'''<remarks>
'''Auto-generated field.
'''To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
'''</remarks>
Protected WithEvents txtName As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
'''<summary>
'''txtEmail control.
'''</summary>
'''<remarks>
'''Auto-generated field.
'''To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
'''</remarks>
Protected WithEvents txtEmail As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
'''<summary>
'''txtPassword control.
'''</summary>
'''<remarks>
'''Auto-generated field.
'''To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
'''</remarks>
Protected WithEvents txtPassword As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
'''<summary>
'''txtRepasword control.
'''</summary>
'''<remarks>
'''Auto-generated field.
'''To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
'''</remarks>
Protected WithEvents txtRepassword As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
'''<summary>
'''txtCountry control.
'''</summary>
'''<remarks>
'''Auto-generated field.
'''To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
'''</remarks>
Protected WithEvents txtCountry As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
'''<summary>
'''txtCollege control.
'''</summary>
'''<remarks>
'''Auto-generated field.
'''To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
'''</remarks>
Protected WithEvents txtCollege As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
'''<summary>
'''txtPhone control.
'''</summary>
'''<remarks>
'''Auto-generated field.
'''To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
'''</remarks>
Protected WithEvents txtPhone As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
```

Comment: Double check the name and type of your control.  It seems like txtName is either not the name of a control or, if it is, it isn't a control type with the Text property.

Comment: You can't get txtName value at the time of declaration; you need to try to capture at button click or some other event where you needed those values

Comment: @techspider i also tried capture textbox value at button click but same error occurs

Comment: @Kalmino I checked no any problem in Contol

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Some error checking will help you avoid stack traces

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text) Then
Dim name As String = txtName.Text
End If
```